Github project deployment issue
I'm trying to create GitHub link for my react application https://github.com/THIPPESH57/Tic-Tac-Toe ,so that any one can access my application, but the GitHub page link is redirecting the link to ReadMe file, this is the LINK provided.
I tried crating new repository but it still redirect the link to readme file only,

You didn't build your project

https://github.com/THIPPESH57/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/gh-pages  , i build my project using npm run build

But you pushed the source, not the dist. There should only be html, css and js files

Hi thanks for that, I'm new to GitHub , can you please assist me how can i push only those files.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I assume what you are trying to achieve here is to host your app on GitHub pages.
You would need to follow the deployment guidelines for create-react-app
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages
